# Binary options and European option is similar?

Tags: option-strategies

European options and binary (digital) options is similar?
How apply the Black & Scholes formula on binary option?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [good write-up of this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_option).

Comment: They are both path-independent; and yes by googling you'll find your answers in both theories and implementations.